# Filter and order a list from another abstract class using stream java

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, java-stream

I have an abstract class which is a list `Collection` and it has three classes that inherit the class `Collection`. They are `Ground, Sky and Sea`.
Now I'd want from another class to choose one of these types and order it.

```
public List<Collection> getCollectionsPerType(String type){
List<Integer> collection= collection.stream()   
.filter(collection -> collection.getType() == Collection.??)
```

I got until here but then I realize that I don't know how to obtain the types from the list.
And I have another question, to use `stream()` do I have to create the method in the Collection class, because this is what Eclipse says.

Comment: Why don't you use `filter(t -> t instanceof WantedClass)`?

Comment: I mistype when i wrote it

Comment: *Now i'd want from another class to choose one of these type and order it.* -- What do you mean by this?

Comment: That i have the class Inventory which wants to choose on the and order its elements

Comment: Still unclear, well at least for me. Share the abstract class along with the other related information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupingBy` as a collector, if that's what you mean - it's not entirely clear.

```
public List<Collection<?>> getCollectionByType(Class<?> type) {

    Map<Class<?>, List<Collection<?>>> map = 
        collections.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getClass));

    return map.get(type);
}
```